# How can I find the N most repeated elements in a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

here is what I've got:

```
dict = {"a":2, "b":10, "c":5, "d":10, "e":6, "f":3, "g":4}
```

I want to find the 3 most repeated elements in this dictionary so the output would be:

```
{"b":10, "d":10, "e":6}
```

Comment: Why is 6 the third position, and not 2?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `dict(collections.Counter(my_dict).most_common(3))`

Comment: `most_common`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common

Answer (score 1):

```
import operator 
sorted(a.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:3]
```

You could do this by sorted as well.